# DynamicLinksClient is not available error while implementing firebase dynamic links in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

W/GoogleApiManager( 1448): The service for com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.internal.DynamicLinksClient is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
E/flutter ( 1448): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_dynamic_links/unknown] com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: DynamicLinks.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
E/flutter ( 1448):

I had followed the exact steps given in https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/usage

Comment: I have this too, on emulator Android 11 (API 30)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure, that your device have google services.

For emulator: create one with play store icon. [image]

For physical device make sure that this device is not in banned from google lists. For example Huawei devices.

based on this issues: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8397

Comment: And what if the device is banned?

Comment: then you cant use google dynamic links on this device and your app will crash. You should than make another version of your app without dynamic links. I encountered this in my apps and just have to show Sorry message for users :(